# Different ways to add functions to Javascript object

Tags: javascript

In Javascript is there any difference between these two ways of adding a function to an object?  Is one preferable for any reason?

```
function ObjA() {
    this.AlertA = function() { alert("A"); };
}
ObjA.prototype.AlertB = function() { alert("B"); };

var A = new ObjA();
A.AlertA();
A.AlertB();
```

Comment: Possbible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422476/javascript-setting-methods-through-prototype-object-or-in-constructor-differenc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure there is a difference. If you define `this.AlertA`, you are defining a method that is local  for the instance of `ObjA`. If you add `AlertA` to the prototype of the `ObjA` *constructor*, it is defined for every instance of `ObjA`. The latter is, in this case, more efficient, because it's only assigned once, whilst a local method is assigned every time you create an instance of `ObjA`.

So using `this.AlertA` in:

```
var A = new ObjA, 
    B = new ObjA,
    C = new ObjA;
```

for A, B and C the constructor has to add the method `AlertA`. `AlertB` on the other hand, is only added once. You can check that using:

```
function ObjA() {
        alert('adding AlertA!');
        this.AlertA = function() { 
            alert("A"); 
        };

        if (!ObjA.prototype.AlertB) {
            alert('adding AlertB!');
            ObjA.prototype.AlertB = function() { 
                alert("B"); 
            };
        }
}

var A = new ObjA,  //=>  alerts adding AlertA! and alerts adding AlertB!
    B = new ObjA,  //=>  alerts adding AlertA!
    C = new ObjA;  //=>  alerts adding AlertA!
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the object constructor will assign a copy of that function to every new instance of your object.  Using prototyping will result in one function being shared across all instances.