# What is difference between method attached to prototype or object instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I am a bit confused about the usage of prototypes in Javascript.

Let's take the following example:

(1)

```
   function Rectangle(w, h) { 
      this.width=w; 
      this.height=h; 
      this.area=function() { this.width * this.height; }
   }
```

And a similar case where the area is attached to a prototype as follows:

(2)

```
   function Rectangle(w, h) { 
      this.width=w; 
      this.height=h; 
   }
   Rectangle.prototype.area=function() { this.width * this.height; }
```

- What is the diffrence between (1) and (2) ?
- When would you use (1) or (2) for writing methods on classes?

Comment: `this.prototype` doesn't exist.

Comment: Right: one works, the other doesn't :-)

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422476/javascript-setting-methods-through-prototype-object-or-in-constructor-differen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prototypes are best shown differently.

```
function rectangle(w, h) {
    var rect = {};
    rect.width=w; 
    rect.height=h; 
    rect.area=function() { return this.width * this.height; };
    return rect;
}
```

vs

```
var Rectangle = {
    area: function() { return this.width * this.height; }
}

function rectangle(w, h) {
    var rect = Object.create(Rectangle);
    rect.width=w; 
    rect.height=h; 
    return rect;
}
```

The idea is simple, you put common stuff on a prototype object and you then inherit from it.

As for when you want to use the prototype? Always.

Of course you probably want to [Improve ES5 OO with sugar](http://raynos.org/blog/17/Improving-ES5-OO-with-sugar)